# Passing variables between theme preprocess hooks

Tags: 8, theming, webforms

I'm a newbie to Drupal 8 and PHP coding in general so I hope my approach is not too much out of the lines. I'm trying to theme some parts of my website by fiddling a bit with templates, what I need to do is to get a value of a specific preprocess hook function and pass it to another one, to be more precise I need to print the page title of the currently visualized wizard page of my Webform into the Page Title block, so it would show both the form main title and the current page title, basically generate a twig variable to put inside my page-title.html.twig template.

to get that value I've been doing the following:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_webform(&$variables){
  //Gets the current wizard page id
  $current_page = $variables['element']['progress']['#current_page'];
  //gets its correspondig value
  $page_title = $variables['element']['elements'][$current_page]['#title'];
  $variables['page_title'] = $page_title;
}
```

But of course, the value **{{ page_title }}** would only be available inside the webform.html.twig template and not inside the page-title.html.twig template.

Is there a way to have those variables available inside the `MYTHEME_preprocess_page_title` hook instead? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: You can't pass variables in general, but you can pass the title by setting `$form['#title']`. Probably too late late in this hook, better try a form alter hook.